# Prove that a number with 30 digits cannot have more than 100 prime factors.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I know that the a number with more than  100 prime factors must be  larger than

$2 ^ {100}$, so it must have more than 30 digits but i am having trouble with proof.

I was given 
Hint: every prime number is $≥ 2$.
 Can someone help me connect the two ideas.

Comment: Hint #2: $p_1p_2\cdots p_{100}\ge 2\cdot 2\cdots 2=2^{100}$.

Comment: Hint for a calculator-free world: $2^{100} = (2^{10})^{10} = (1024)^{10} > (10^{3})^{10} = 10^{30}$, which has $31$ digits.

Answer (score 2):

Call the $100$ prime factors $p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots,p_{100}$.  Then
\begin{align}
p_1 & \ge 2 \\
p_2 & \ge 2 \\
p_3 & \ge 2 \\
& {}\,\,\, \vdots \\
p_{100} & \ge 2
\end{align}
Therefore
$$
p_1 \times p_2 \times p_3 \times \cdots \times p_{100} \ge \underbrace{2\times2\times2\times\cdots\times2}_\text{100 factors}
$$
and that last number has $31$ digits.

Comment: How do you call in english, when instead of proving "$A\implies B$" you prove "$B'\implies A'$" (obversion? Con-sth?), cause that is what you do here, isn't it? I think that may be confusing for OP.

Comment: Contrapositive.

Comment: @quapka Proof by Contraposition, considers the contrapositive proposition.